# Linkedin Not Pulling Correct Title for URL

Tags: django, url, linkedin-api, title

When I share my website URL on linkedin It picks up the right description but the wrong title.  It shows up as "Recent Comments".  I thought that it would pick up the < title> tags. What exactly does linkedin take for the title?

[image: Here is an exmaple]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this depends on how you're doing the share action.

If you are using the linkedin.com website to post it, there is a crawler that hits the shared URL looking for OpenGraph tags to get that information, and if it cannot find those, it does it's best to interrogate the DOM to determine the title/description values as best as it can guess.

If you are using the Share API (which I would hope is the case given that you are asking the question here on Stack) then the values that the Share uses are whatever you directly provide via the API call - and no additional site crawling is done to try and override/trump the values you provided via your call.

Answer (score 0):

If i am guessing right, it will NOT read the < title > tag but the < h1 > tag.